# Shell script: use if on environmental variable

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a shell script like this,

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ -z "$ENVIRON" ]; then
    echo "no env set"
elif  [ "$ENVIRON" == "test" ]; then
    echo "test mode"
else
    echo "production mode"
fi
```

when I run this im getting error,

> [: test: unexpected operator

I also tried changing to `elif  [ $ENVIRON == "test" ]; then`, but getting the same error. When I run this on my mac I get the expected result:

```
tw tmp $ cat script.sh 
#! /bin/sh
if [ -z "$ENVIRON" ]; then
    echo "no env set"
elif  [ "$ENVIRON" == "test" ]; then
    echo "test mode"
else
    echo "production mode"
fi
tw tmp $ ENVIRON=test sh script.sh 
test mode
```

But getting error while running the exact same script in ubuntu

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: `==` is not valid in `[`; see the specification describing its behavior in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: it's valid in some shells such as Bash

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, as a nonportable extension yes, but `sh` is not guaranteed to offer any such extensions. And if someone wants extended test syntax, they should be using `[[` instead to be explicit about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single `=`:

```
elif  [ "$ENVIRON" = "test" ]; then
```

See https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2039#testing-equality